# SCX-4521F scanner is not working ubuntu 14.04 amd64

Tags: 14.04, samsung, scanner, sane, xsane

I installed the Samsung Unified Driver for the scx 4521F and printing works.

Neither program can find a scanner though: sane-find-scanner, SimpleScan and Xsane all reporting "no scanner found"
Also running all three as root produces the same output.

Any ideas how to solve that?

Additional information:

- saned is deactivated
- MFD is connected via USB